# Change how Closure compiler names private members

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I am working with a large JS library that is minified using `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`, and I'm looking to change the way that is renames members.

Here is what I have as input:

```
/**
 * This is my class
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} name
 * */
function MyClass(name) {
    /**
     * I want this public member to stay the same in the output since it will be exported
     * @expose
     * */
    this.exposedMember = name;
    /**
     * But this member is meant to only be used by this class
     * @private
     * */
    this.privateMember = "private";
}
var myObj = new MyClass("Jack");
myObj.exposedMember;    // => "Jack"
myObj.privateMember;    // => "private"
```

Here is what I get as an output:

```
var myObj = new MyClass("Jack");
myObj.exposedMember;    // => "Jack"
myObj.Rc;               // => "private"
```

Here is what I **want** as an output:

```
var myObj = new MyClass("Jack");
myObj.exposedMember;    // => "Jack"
myObj._Rc;              // => "private"
```

The reason is that I am also working with the Google Maps JS API and I have had a couple of instances where my private members collide with theirs from one version to the next.  Having control over my own private members where I can choose to prefix them with `_` (or `$`, or whatever) will eliminate the problem.

Is there something in the command line that can help me do this?  If not, is there a plugin for Closure Compiler that can do this?  Something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Options to direct this type of renaming are not exposed via command line flags. This would require a custom build of the compiler.

In general, it's always dangerous to add properties to external objects unless their full definition is known. The Google Maps API is particularly tricky on this front.

The only safe way to do this is to define a custom extern for the Maps objects you are extending:

extern:

```
/** @const */ google.maps.Marker.prototype.data = {};
```

source:

```
const myMarker = new google.maps.Marker();
myMarker.data.mySafeProperty = 'foo';
```

However, this breaks down with true class extension. That's never safe without knowing the full type signature.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know where in Closure I'd need to modify to override the Closure private member naming scheme would you?